# JSF error when double clicking command link

Tags: jsf

I have an error in my application which only happens when a user double clicks a command link.

What appears to be happening is that the first click correctly does the post then redirect and creates new instances of the WebBeans with the correct view param against them.

The second click tries to restore the old view in the POST, which will nolonger exist so creates a new one and new `ViewScoped` beans associated.  When it comes to reading the view param in the `@PostConstruct` this is null and an exception is thrown later in the code.

Has anyone experienced something like this?  How's best to code around it?  I'm trying to avoid detecting and stopping this on the client since I'd like to understand the problem more rather than hiding it behind JS!

Comment: Long shot: As the first click already redirects and therefore invalidates your originating `ViewScoped` bean, a second click tries to use the already invalidated `ViewScoped` bean to construct the `POST` parameters which fails obviously. A solution would be a) to teach your users *not* to double-click links in your application (most casual users don't seem to be able to differentiate between a "normal" web page where you can navigate via "back" button, bookmark, reload etc. and a web *application* built with JSF) or b) to avoid commandlinks and use "normal" links with query parameters instead.

Comment: To validate my assumption, you could change your originating bean from `ViewScoped` to e.g. `SessionScoped` and see whether your target bean is correctly populated twice.

Comment: @smutje Thanks for the information, your long shot sounds plausible to me!  I'll try playing with the scopes to see if that changes anything.  I'm trying to avoid "normal" links to keep dreaded `ViewExpiredExceptions` at bay!

Comment: what about "disabling" the link by removing the href attribute via JavaScript on the first click? `$(".mybutton").removeAttr('href');`